# Adding to a large Java collection, performance bottleneck

Tags: java, performance, collections

I am trying to add a million objects into a list. The time it takes to do it, is longer than i have patience to wait for. It also seems to take progressively longer to carry on with each step.

```
    int size = 1000000;
    Deque<DatastoreElement> content = new LinkedList<DatastoreElement>();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        String k = Utils.getRandomStringOfLength(20);
        String v = Utils.getRandomStringOfLength(300); // goes faster with smaller number

        int metaHash = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        KVPair kvp = new KVPair(k, v);
        DatastoreElement dse = new DatastoreElement(metaHash, kvp);

        content.addLast(dse); // confirmed problem is here

        if (i % 10000 == 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

I tried adding content to the `List`, `Set` with very similar results. It starts up fast and chokes after some number.

What collection should i be using to store a large number of like elements? Am i missing something simple here?

Comment: Try an `ArrayList` pre-allocated for 1,000,000 elements

Comment: The answer depends on how you intend to use the data.  Unless you need to be able to iterate in both directions, use an `ArrayList` instead of a `LinkedList`.  Once you have your million objects loaded, what will you be doing with them?

Comment: Maybe the JVM is trashing. Try increasing the memory limit with -mx

Comment: @Jam I doubt very much that `add`ing elements to an `ArrayList` would cause a significant bottleneck. Are you sure the bottleneck isn't in making the objects themselves?

Comment: @Jeffrey actually, [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) since currently he's using `Deque`

Comment: Also tried using array `DatastoreElement content[] = new DatastoreElement[size]; content[i] = dse;` - same problem

Comment: @Jeffrey With add() commented, everything flies

Comment: @Jam If you comment out `add`, the JIT might just optimize the object creation out completely since it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Jam in order to nail the problem down to a particular call, I suggest you try and profile your code with a proper profiler, such as JVisualVM which comes with JDK

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue is not with collections in general, and *not* with the `LinkedList` as shown (which has `O(1)` adding characteristics).

The likely suspect is thus thrashing/swap of memory. *Make sure the JVM has enough memory, and the system has more ..*

Switching from `LinkedList` to `ArrayList` (or `ArrayDeque`) will keep `O(1)` *amortized* performance, but **may** have *slightly* less overhead per-item. (The overhead, and if such a reduction would even matter, depends upon the size of the objects added and the fill ratios of the backing stores.)

Comment: Actually `LinkedList` will always be worse since the memory nodes are not contiguous memory like in an `ArrayList` which can be cached in the same pages

Comment: @Cratylus That's for the JVM to deal with :) A counter-example *might* be after a "backing double" operation where the fill ratio is about 50%. But I would not wager money either way without some tests ..

Comment: JVM?You think that JVM does these kind of optimizations for requests of nodes of size `X`?

Comment: Usually lot of small objects don't have good locality.Why would this be different for the `LinkedList`?

Comment: `ArrayList` will almost certainly do better at memory locality than `LinkedList`.

Comment: Object allocation in modern JVMs are very cheap.

Comment: Using simple arrays now, with `Xmx1024m`. Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- ArrayList has already been suggested (in a linked list, each item/node implies an additional object).
- Also (previously suggested as well), if you use an array-based collection, try to construct/resize into an adequate length.
- Also, if memory is an issue, you might want to use the Flyweight pattern with the string elements `String#intern()`, so redundant instances can be collected.